# How to make a query statement with AWS timestream for pagination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, t-sql, pagination, paging, amazon-timestream

I used limit and offset for pagenation but it seems that offset is not available here.

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_DB
LIMIT 10   OFFSET 0
```

I want to get some aws pages or hints for implementing pagenation here.

I looked up the aws page and couldn't get a hint.

Comment: `LIMIT` is not a T-SQL keyword; are you *sure* you're using T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking for more results available beyond the initial query, you need to use thea NEXT_TOKEN value :

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_DB
NEXT_TOKEN '<value>'
LIMIT 10
```